# Getting the corresponding cell value for a specific 'string' from excel sheet in python language for plotting a line/scatter plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests, spyder

I want to plot a line/scatter plot for `country name == 'Argentina'` vs its corresponding 'value' only, out of the entire data.

Sample data

[image: Y]

[total data file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1L7BmvBfALRszFmG2xcsSVTHPChP_8WsC)

This is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/kdandebo/Desktop/Models/Python excercise/Data3.xlsx")
x = (df['Country Name'])

#Although i have figured out x cannot be compared to a string named Argentina, i couldnt think of any other way, Also ive tried the below version too, but none works
#if (df['Country Name'] == 'Argentina'):
#    y = (df['Value'])
for x == ("Argentina"):
    y = (df['Value'])
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: it's hard when you take your first step in programming, and everyone has different ways to learn. Python however has a great advantage in that it's very easy to see what one tries to do, and thus for oneself see what is going wrong. You only need 2 lines to make what you want, 1 line to read the excel, and one to make the plot, and you do it by df.plot(). Exactly what you need to write I will let you figure out from the pandas documentation related to plotting. if you are in spyder you can use the debugger to see what your code actually does, it's a great way to learn.

Comment: xlsx file or a sample needed

Comment: one thing you can check is what happens when you write `for x == ('Argentina')`. I'm pretty sure that does not do what you intend to achieve.

Comment: Added the entire file as "total data file"

Comment: yes , I am using Spyder and yeah , ive tried debugging , which is lil unclear

Comment: well, if your code in spyder actually looks like you have it in your post, I would expect that you get errors. Do you have errors? Also what do you see if you do `print(x)` directly after `x` is defined? And what do you see if you print `df['Country Name'] == 'Argentina'`?

Comment: And same for `df[df['Country Name'] == 'Argentina']`?

Comment: your best debugger in python when learning is just to print your variables to actually see what you have in them. Good luck in your endevour to learn a bit of programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main problem was reading spread sheet file and selecting the right sheet

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xl = pd.ExcelFile("Data3.xlsx")
df=xl.parse("Data")

x = df[df['Country Name']=="Argentina"]
plt.scatter(x['Country Name'],x['Value'])
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: thaaanq u soo much.. that was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

this code is self contained and provides an answer the question.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Series Name': ['GDP']*4,
                   'Country Name': ['Argentina']*2 + ['Bolivia']*2,
                   'Time': [2001, 2002, 2001, 2002],
                   'Value': [1, 3, 2, 4]})
#print(df)
df[df['Country Name'] == 'Argentina'].plot.scatter('Time', 'Value')
```

quite often answers to questions like this are found in the library documentation under examples or tutorials.

Comment: thaanq soo much, that was very helpful alternative approach

Answer (score 0):

Before you start make plot, first you ought to extract data about Argentina.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Define the headers
headers = ["SeriesName", "CountryName", "Time", "Value"]
# Read in the Excel file
df_raw = pd.read_excel("C:/1/Data3.xlsx",header=None, names=headers)
# extract data to only Argentina
country = ["Argentina"]
# Create a copy of the data with only the Argentina
df = df_raw[df_raw.CountryName.isin(country)].copy()
#print(df)
```

After extracting you can use only Pandas to make plot.

```
'''Pandas plot'''
df.plot.line(x='Time', y='Value', c='Red',legend =0, title = "ARGENTINA GDP per capita")
plt.show()
```

You can also make plot by Matplotlib library and Seaborn or Plotly.

```
# Create plot from matplotlib
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(df.Value, df.Time)
plt.xlabel('GPD Value')
plt.ylabel('Years')
plt.title('''ARGENTINA
          GDP per capita (constant 2010 US$) ''')
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceO6m.png)

Seaborn plot

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.scatterplot(x="Value", y="Time", data=df, color = 'DarkBlue')
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.9)
plt.suptitle("ARGENTINA GDP per capita")
plt.show()
```

Plotly plot

```
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace = go.Scatter(x = df.Time, y = df.Value)
data = [trace]
plotly.offline.plot({"data": data}, filename='Argentina GDP.html')
```